# Calling a function from a class in main

Tags: python

I seem to be making a stupid mistake that I cant find. Im simply trying to call my functions from my record class and having an invalid syntax error despite looking at sample code and trying to emulate the syntax.

Ive tried following tutorials and calling the function in every which way so the problem may not be in the calling of the function but something else I feel.

## class definitions

```
class record:

    def __init__(self,telephone,lastname,firstname):
        self.telephone = telephone
        self.lastname = lastname
        self.firstname = firstname

    def addrecord(self,x,y,z):
        x = input('Enter telephone number')
        y = input('Enter lastname')
        z = input('Enter firstname')
        phonebook.append(record(x,y,z))
        return

    def deleterecord(self,x):
        phonebook[x-1].pop
        return
```

## Main

```
phonebook = record[]
addrecord(515,'fin','matt')
print(phonebook[0].firstname)
deleterecord(1)
print(phonebook[0].firstname)
```

If all this works I expect the output to be
"matt"
"null"

Comment: sorry my main is a clusterfuck. It didnt newline anywhere for some reason.

Comment: Please provide the full traceback of the error.

Comment: Also, for future reference, immediately after pasting code into your question, select it and either type Ctrl+K or click the `{}` button in the editor interface. That will format your code properly.

Comment: `record[]` is invalid, it should be `record()`.

Comment: To be honest, there are a lot of issues in your code.

Comment: Sanyash Im coming from C# and got an assignment to write a python webapp. maybe i can make my intentions more clear. Im trying to make a simple phonebook app where you can add, delete, and display the list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a number of problems with your code:

- you are defining phonebook otuside of the class
- in `deleterecord` you should call `phonebook.pop(x)`.
- there should be two classes that handle the phonebook and records, and the record could be modeled using a `namedtuple`.
- there are syntax errors like calling `record[]` which is not valid Python.

Alternative implementation:

```
from collections import namedtuple

PhoneRecord = namedtuple("PhoneRecord", ['firstname', 'lastname', 'telephone'])

class PhoneBook:

    def __init__(self):
        self._phonebook = []

    def addrecord(self, record):
        self._phonebook.append(record)
        return self._phonebook.index(record)

    def deleterecord(self, i):
        self._phonebook.pop(i)

phonebook = PhoneBook()
record_index = phonebook.addrecord(PhoneRecord(firstname="matt", lastname="snow", telephone="25512521"))
print(phonebook._phonebook)
phonebook.deleterecord(record_index)
print(phonebook._phonebook)
```

which will yield in the console:

```
[PhoneRecord(firstname='matt', lastname='snow', telephone='25512521')]
[]
```

Comment: @MatthewFinateri did this help you out?

Comment: This helped thank you. Ive just gotten home and used your code in conjunction with mine to get it working as I wanted thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

The simplified version of your question is, given code

```
records = []
records.append("matt")
print(records[0])
del records[0]
print(records[0])
```

why don't I get the following output

```
"matt"
None
```

Instead, you get an `IndexError` exception.

The reason is that you are accessing an element beyond the size of the list, and Python handles this by raising an exception rather than returning None.

Comment: Note that the question states that he's getting a syntax error.

Comment: In my answer I was trying to look past those problems and answer why the code in the question will never work like that.